# How to fill a dictionary from a list using regex?

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I have a list ("output"). I want to extract values from it and put them in a dictionary.
So far, I can extract some words using regex. But I do not know how to fill the dictionary.

THIS IS MY ATTEMPT

```
output = ['labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: img0000.jpg \n', '\n', '----INFERENCE TIME----\n', 'Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.\n', 'time: 6.0ms\n', '-------RESULTS--------\n','results: wall clock\n', 'score: 0.25781\n', '##################################### \n', ' \n', '\n']

mydict = {}

regex1 = re.compile(fr'(\w+:)\s(.*)')
match_regex1 = list(filter(regex1.match, output))
match = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in match_regex1]
```

THE DICTIONARY MUST LOOK LIKE THIS:

```
{
'Model': "efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite",
'Image': "img0000.jpg",
'time': "6.0",
'results': "wall_clock",
'score': :0.25781"
}
```

THE LIST LOOKS LIKE THIS:

[image]

EDIT

I have make this loop. Althoug it does not work properly:

```
for i in output:
    reg1 = re.search(r'(\w+:)\s(.*)', i)
    if "Model" in i:
        mydict.setdefault("Model", {reg1.group()})
        print(mydict)
```

Comment: Dictionary doesn't show `'labels: imagenet_labels.txt`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary. I can remove it from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, based on the list `match`:

```
import re
output = ['labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: img0000.jpg \n', '\n', '----INFERENCE TIME----\n', 'Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.\n', 'time: 6.0ms\n', '-------RESULTS--------\n','results: wall clock\n', 'score: 0.25781\n', '##################################### \n', ' \n', '\n']

mydict = {}

regex1 = re.compile(fr'(\w+:)\s(.*)')
match_regex1 = list(filter(regex1.match, output))
match = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in match_regex1]

features_wanted='ModelImagetimeresultsscore'

dct={i.replace(' ','').split(':')[0]:i.replace(' ','').split(':')[1] for i in match if i.replace(' ','').split(':')[0] in features_wanted}
mydict=dct
print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'Model': 'efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite', 'Image': 'img0000.jpg', 'time': '6.0ms', 'results': 'wallclock', 'score': '0.25781'}
```

**Explain of dct:** It's a [Dictionary Comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension) and iterates over the list match, so here is an example of the iteration with `'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite'`:

```
#First check if it is a feature wanted:
i='Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite'
i.replace(' ','')
>>>'Model:efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite'
i.replace(' ','').split(':')
>>>['Model','efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite']
i.replace(' ','').split(':')[0] in features_wanted  #'Model' in 'ModelImagetimeresultsscore'
>>>True
#If it is in features_wanted, an item like this is append to the dictionary:
i.replace(' ','').split(':')[0]:i.replace(' ','').split(':')[1]
>>>'Model':'efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite'
```

Comment: Can you explain me: "dct = ..."?

Comment: Sure, just added an explanation, I hope it'll be clear.

Answer (score 1):

for filling dicionary you can use this script:

```
for item in match:
    key , value = item.split(":")
    mydict[key] = value
```

so the result is something like:

```
{'labels': ' imagenet_labels.txt ', 'Model': ' efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite ', 'Image': ' img0000.jpg ', 'Note': ' The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.', 'time': ' 6.0ms', 'results': ' wall clock', 'score': ' 0.25781'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = ['labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: img0000.jpg \n', '\n', '----INFERENCE TIME----\n', 'Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.\n', 'time: 6.0ms\n', '-------RESULTS--------\n','results: wall clock\n', 'score: 0.25781\n', '##################################### \n', ' \n', '\n']

d = dict( re.findall(r'(\w+):\s*([^\n]+?)\s*$', ' '.join(output), flags=re.M) )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'Image': 'img0000.jpg',
 'Model': 'efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite',
 'Note': 'The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading '
         'the model into Edge TPU memory.',
 'labels': 'imagenet_labels.txt',
 'results': 'wall clock',
 'score': '0.25781',
 'time': '6.0ms'}
```

Comment: OP  uses `re.match`, so you need `^` with `re.findall` pattern. Use `r'^(\w+):\s*(.*\S)'`, or `r'^(\w+):[^\S\n]*(.*\S)'` (since `\s` matches line breaks).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew When I use `d = dict( re.findall(r'^(\w+):\s*(.*\S)', ' '.join(output), flags=re.M) )` the output is just `{'labels': 'imagenet_labels.txt'}`

Answer (score 0):

Since the delimiter of the fields is always `:` is you can use the `str.split` method instead of regex for better efficiency:

```
dict(s.split(': ', 1) for s in map(str.rstrip, output) if ': ' in s)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SnoopyBoringComputationalscience

Comment: How will it change if the "output" was bigger? I mean if having many "Model:", "Image:", etc?